# Why does `1, 2, 3` evaluate to `3` in JS?

Tags: javascript, language-lawyer

In the example below, variable `r` will have value `d`.

```js
const r = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'][1, 2, 3]

console.log(r);
```

I understand that this is because the expression `1, 2, 3` evaluates to `3`, the last token.

Is there a practical reason behind `1, 2, 3` being a valid expression and evaluation to `3` in JS?

Comment: The mystery is regarding how comma operator works. It is used to separate multiple expressions and returns the last one.

Comment: Both duplicates are excellent and appropriate and adequately answer the question of "is there a practical reason..."  This question is redundant, and I see no need to reopen it.  Perhaps the reopen voter could please include a comment to indicate the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because in the expression above, you are using the comma (`,`) as the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_operator), which

> Evaluates each of its operands (from left to right) and returns the value of the last operand.